# How to query json data in angular 2

Tags: json, angular

I want to query JSON data based on some conditions using angular2

My json is:

```
{
"logsArray":[
    {
        "Id": "1",
        "ProjectName": "Project01",
        "ModuleName": "Module01",
        "MethodName": "Method01",
        "Message": "MessageMessage",
        "MessageDetails": "MessageDetailsMessageDetails",
        "LogType": "LogType",
        "CreatedDate": "Fri May 04 2012 01:17:07 GMT-0700 (PDT)",
        "CreatedBy": "User01"
    },
    {
        "Id": "2",
        "ProjectName": "Project02",
        "ModuleName": "Module01",
        "MethodName": "Method03",
        "Message": "MessageMessage",
        "MessageDetails": "MessageDetailsMessageDetails",
        "LogType": "LogType",
        "CreatedDate": "Fri May 04 2012 01:17:07 GMT-0700 (PDT)",
        "CreatedBy": "User01"
    },
    {
        "Id": "3",
        "ProjectName": "Project03",
        "ModuleName": "Module05",
        "MethodName": "Method01",
        "Message": "MessageMessage",
        "MessageDetails": "MessageDetailsMessageDetails",
        "LogType": "LogType",
        "CreatedDate": "Fri May 04 2012 01:17:07 GMT-0700 (PDT)",
        "CreatedBy": "User01"
    },
    {
        "Id": "4",
        "ProjectName": "Project01",
        "ModuleName": "Module07",
        "MethodName": "Method01",
        "Message": "MessageMessage",
        "MessageDetails": "MessageDetailsMessageDetails",
        "LogType": "LogType",
        "CreatedDate": "Fri May 04 2012 01:17:07 GMT-0700 (PDT)",
        "CreatedBy": "User01"
    },
    {
        "Id": "5",
        "ProjectName": "Project03",
        "ModuleName": "Module01",
        "MethodName": "Method10",
        "Message": "MessageMessage",
        "MessageDetails": "MessageDetailsMessageDetails",
        "LogType": "LogType",
        "CreatedDate": "Fri May 04 2012 01:17:07 GMT-0700 (PDT)",
        "CreatedBy": "User01"
    },
    {
        "Id": "6",
        "ProjectName": "Project06",
        "ModuleName": "Module01",
        "MethodName": "Method05",
        "Message": "MessageMessage",
        "MessageDetails": "MessageDetailsMessageDetails",
        "LogType": "LogType",
        "CreatedDate": "Fri May 04 2012 01:17:07 GMT-0700 (PDT)",
        "CreatedBy": "User01"
    },
    {
        "Id": "7",
        "ProjectName": "Project03",
        "ModuleName": "Module03",
        "MethodName": "Method07",
        "Message": "MessageMessage",
        "MessageDetails": "MessageDetailsMessageDetails",
        "LogType": "LogType",
        "CreatedDate": "Fri May 04 2012 01:17:07 GMT-0700 (PDT)",
        "CreatedBy": "User01"
    },
    {
        "Id": "8",
        "ProjectName": "Project04",
        "ModuleName": "Module03",
        "MethodName": "Method05",
        "Message": "MessageMessage",
        "MessageDetails": "MessageDetailsMessageDetails",
        "LogType": "LogType",
        "CreatedDate": "Fri May 04 2012 01:17:07 GMT-0700 (PDT)",
        "CreatedBy": "User01"
    }
]
}
```

I want to get the particular property based on some conditions like

1. Distinct ProjectNames where PojectName = Project03
2. Distincts ModuleNames where ModuleName = Module02 && MethodName = Method01
3. Distinct Method Names ProjectName = Project01

Comment: When you use the query you can add `equalTo` operator or use a projection into collection of items via OGNL

Comment: Can you give some example with query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use angular 2 http get method to get json data in your angular service.

   `this.http.get(./filename.json)
   .map((res:Response)=>res.json())
   .subscribe(data=>this.temp=data.logsArray.filter())`
2. Or you can use filter method of Observables.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out the [Angular2 Json API library](https://github.com/ghidoz/angular2-jsonapi)?

Once you have it setup, it looks something like this:

```
this.datastore.findRecord(logsArray, '1').subscribe(
   (post: logsArray) => console.log(post)
);
```

Answer (score -1):

You mean like this?

```
var nameSpace = angular.module("GuitarApp", []);

nameSpace.controller("GuitarFunction", ['$scope','$http', function($scope, $http)
        {    
            $http.get('js/data.json').success (function(data){ // json call
                $scope.guitarVariable = data;
        });

    }]
);
```

Source: https://blog.hfarazm.com/angularjs-service/